# Can't received a response in express NodeJs from a module & model

Tags: node.js, express, response

Well, hello guys !

I would like to understand why in my module from express NodeJs, when I do a function from a model, the response is not setted/received in this following code.

```
 module.exports.AjouterPersonne = function(request, response){
   response.title = 'Ajout des personnes';

   if(request.session.nom)
   {
     response.nom = request.session.nom;
   }

   if(request.body.nom && request.body.prenom && request.body.tel && request.body.email
     && request.body.login && request.body.pwd && request.body.categorie)
   {
     response.categorie = 1;

     model4.getListeDepartement(function (err, result){
               if (err) {
                   // gestion de l'erreur
                   console.log(err);
                   return;
               }

               response.dept = result;
     });

     model5.getListeDivision(function (err, result){
               if (err) {
                   // gestion de l'erreur
                   console.log(err);
                   return;
               }
               response.div = result;
     });

     console.log('value of res.div'+response.div);

   }
   response.render('ajouterPersonne', response);
};
```

"response.categorie" is setted but response.dept & response.div are undefined outside the model line.

I thank you in advance for your help ;)

Comment: Have you checked that the callback function in you're model# get functions is't async, such that the `response.render` is executed before the callback functions are called?

Comment: your ``getListeDepartement`` and ``getListeDivision`` are async methods. Before executing these 2, the ``response.render`` is firing. So you are not getting these values in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can see data in your response, if you write something like -

``
module.exports.AjouterPersonne = function(request, response){
   response.title = 'Ajout des personnes';
   if(request.session.nom)
   {
     response.nom = request.session.nom;
   }
   if(request.body.nom && request.body.prenom && request.body.tel &&
     request.body.email
     && request.body.login && request.body.pwd && request.body.categorie)
   {
     response.categorie = 1;

```
 model4.getListeDepartement(function (err, result){
           if (err) {
               // gestion de l'erreur
               console.log(err);
               return;
           }
           response.dept = result;
           model5.getListeDivision(function (err, result){
             if (err) {
                 // gestion de l'erreur
                 console.log(err);
                 return;
             }
             response.div = result;
             console.log('value of res.div'+response.div);
              response.render('ajouterPersonne', response);               
           });
    });
```

}
};
``

Also if you use `node async` library in your work, it will be better coding.

[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Hope this will help you

Thanks